# Pass array to component in Angular without controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish to pass an array to a component in Angular 1, but I'm not inside a controller (nor do I want to create one - component-only approach). I'm starting with:

```
<user-list users="users"></user-list>
```

Where users is a JS array. Of course it doesn't work, but how to make it?

Comment: this is a directive. You should look this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: if you not want use controller directive directly, you can wrap your component in another component

Comment: This could be a directive *or* a component. If it's a directive, you add `users` to the `scope` definition of the directive and it becomes available at `$scope.yourkey`. If it's a component, you add it to `bindings`, and it (by default) becomes available at `$ctrl.yourkey`.

Comment: There's no problem in reading the variable from inside the component - the bindings are set. The problem is with passing the array itself inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I decided to create a special "proxy component" just to be able to pass scope variables.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by using a directive in angularjs

```
agular.module('app').directive('usersList', function() {
     return {
         restrict : 'E',
         transclude : false,
         scope : {
             users : '@'
         },
     }
};
```

The **template.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users>
      {{ user.firstName }} {{user.lastName }}
</div>
```

In your main application html you simply add the directive

```
<p>
     Some html
</p>
<users-list users="users"></users-list>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, 'users' is undefined in the directive.

Comment: change the '@' to '=', this will cause it to bind to the variable.